# Solve linear system where unknowns are functions

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra

I have the following linear system

```
sys = {-96.34478324298885` a[2] + 74.93701935056998` a[3] + 67.59840434821189` a[4] - 11.426569125926502` a[5] - 34.76407132986651` a[6] == 0, -96.34478324298885` a[1] + 17.45945542572997` a[3] - 26.434983225947008` a[4] + 1.139467223903754` a[5] + 104.18084381930214` a[6] == 0, 74.93701935056998` a[1] + 17.45945542572997` a[2] - 1.6071315084553248` a[4] - 10.755469693552678` a[5] - 80.03387357429195` a[6] == 0, 67.59840434821189` a[1] - 26.434983225947008` a[2] - 1.6071315084553248` a[3] - 14.565409551545223` a[5] - 24.99088006226433` a[6] == 0, -11.426569125926502` a[1] + 1.139467223903754` a[2] - 10.755469693552678` a[3] - 14.565409551545223` a[4] + 35.60798114712065` a[6] == 0, -34.76407132986651` a[1] + 104.18084381930214` a[2] - 80.03387357429195` a[3] - 24.99088006226433` a[4] + 35.60798114712065` a[5] == 0};
```

where the unknowns are the functions `a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4],a[5]`.

If I solve the system with `Solve` I get one solution in terms of `a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6]`

```
Solve[ sys ] 
(*Output:{{a[3] -> 0. + 1.44528 a[1] - 0.445284 a[2], a[4] -> 0. - 0.742935 a[1] + 1.74293 a[2], a[5] -> 0. + 3.70336 a[1] - 2.70336 a[2], a[6] -> 0. + 0.453554 a[1] + 0.546446 a[2]}} *)
```

I want instead to solve this system in terms of `a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4]`. So, I have tried

```
Solve[sys,{a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4]}]
(*Output: {} *)
```

Why do I get empty set? The same applies with  `Solve[sys {a[3],a[4],a[5],a[6]}]`

Comment: Your system has the trivial solution of everything equals 0. I get this in Version12. You need a right hand side.

Comment: ?? It's an homogenous system, obviously there is this solution. However, I get non trivial solution with `Solve[ sys ] ` as explained in the OP

Comment: Your words do not correspond to reality: Solve[ sys] performs {{a[1] -> 0., a[2] -> 0., a[3] -> 0., a[4] -> 0., a[5] -> 0., 
  a[6] -> 0.}} for me. Also MatrixRank[
 Table[Coefficient[sys[[i]][[1]], a[j]], {i, 1, 6}, {j, 1, 6}]] outputs 6.

Comment: Knowing some practices of this forum, I add a screen of your question https://www.dropbox.com/s/gvkebmfcba4irga/screen12.05.19.docx?dl=0

Comment: Sorry @Hugh, I have copied a wrong system. I edited the question.

Comment: @user64494 I don't understand why you have taken a screen of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Solve` command allows inequivalent transforms, `Reduce` doesn't. In view of it

```
sys = {-96.34478324298885` a[2] + 74.93701935056998` a[3] + 
 67.59840434821189` a[4] - 11.426569125926502` a[5] - 
 34.76407132986651` a[6] ==  0, -96.34478324298885` a[1] + 17.45945542572997` a[3] - 
 26.434983225947008` a[4] + 1.139467223903754` a[5] + 
 104.18084381930214` a[6] == 0,74.93701935056998` a[1] + 17.45945542572997` a[2] - 
 1.6071315084553248` a[4] - 10.755469693552678` a[5] - 
 80.03387357429195` a[6] == 0,67.59840434821189` a[1] - 26.434983225947008` a[2] - 
 1.6071315084553248` a[3] - 14.565409551545223` a[5] - 
 24.99088006226433` a[6] == 
0, -11.426569125926502` a[1] + 1.139467223903754` a[2] - 
 10.755469693552678` a[3] - 14.565409551545223` a[4] + 
 35.60798114712065` a[6] == 
0, -34.76407132986651` a[1] + 104.18084381930214` a[2] - 
 80.03387357429195` a[3] - 24.99088006226433` a[4] + 
 35.60798114712065` a[5] == 0};Reduce[sys, Tabl[a[j], {j, 1, 4}]]
```

> a[4] == 0. - 0.368172 a[5] + 1.36817 a[6] && 
>    a[3] == 0. + 0.305166 a[5] + 0.694834 a[6] && 
>    a[2] == 0. - 0.139563 a[5] + 1.13956 a[6] && 
>    a[1] == 0. + 0.168147 a[5] + 0.831853 a[6]

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you want. However, if you want a solution in terms of `a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4]` I guess you want to eliminate `a[5], a[6]`.

Thus

```
Eliminate[sys, {a[5], a[6]}]
```

> a[1] == 0. + 0.796509 a[3] + 0.203491 a[4] && 
>    a[2] == 0. + 0.339516 a[3] + 0.660484 a[4]

Is this what you need?

Comment: The question is, why the command `Solve[sys,{a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4]}]` returns `{}`? I think I am using the syntax wrongly. If you do the following, `sys2=sys/. a[1] -> a1 /. a[2] -> a2 /. a[3] -> a3 /. a[4] -> a4 /. a[5] -> a5 /. a[6] -> a6` and then `Solve[sys2, {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5}]` you get the answer I wanted. I don't want to pass through Replacement Rules